# who does peer work without /var/run/docker.sock?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I see the section of `volumes:  - /var/run/:/host/var/run/` in docker-compose.yml . and peers create the chaincode container via the docker.sock.

Now,

> I have generated the certificates and some channel fils, Then I push it to my git repository.
>
> I redefine the Dockerfile from hyperledger/peer-1.1.0 . And in the peer container, it will pull the certs and channel files from remote git. But I can't handle the problem with the **sock** file. Without the `docker.sock` , I can't execute runtime install command.

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough context of your environment. I suggest to see examples here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/first-network/base/docker-compose-base.yaml#L35 or here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/basic-network/docker-compose.yml#L78

might want to check your `docker info` and also see the user you're running the docker command has permissions on `/var/lib/docker` folder?

Comment: No,in fact,I don’t want to volume the /var/run dictionary to peer container,and I cannot run composer runtime install successful without the docker.sock